# Retrieving SMS in marshmallow

Tags: android, sms, messaging, android-mms

I have a failed SMS in my native inbox. I m not able to retrieve it from my application. The query I use is:

```
content://mms-sms/conversations/73

SELECT transport_type, _id, thread_id, address, body, date, date_sent, read, type, status, locked, error_code, sub, sub_cs, date, date_sent, read, m_type, msg_box, d_rpt, rr, err_type, locked, st FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date * 1 AS normalized_date, 'sms' AS transport_type, _id, thread_id, address, body, date, date_sent, read, type, status, locked, error_code, NULL AS sub, NULL AS sub_cs, date, date_sent, read, NULL AS m_type, NULL AS msg_box, NULL AS d_rpt, NULL AS rr, NULL AS err_type, locked, NULL AS st FROM sms WHERE (thread_id = 73 AND (type != 3)) UNION SELECT DISTINCT date * 1000 AS normalized_date, 'mms' AS transport_type, pdu._id, thread_id, NULL AS address, NULL AS body, date, date_sent, read, NULL AS type, NULL AS status, locked, NULL AS error_code, sub, sub_cs, date, date_sent, read, m_type, msg_box, d_rpt, rr, err_type, locked, st FROM pdu LEFT JOIN pending_msgs ON pdu._id = pending_msgs.msg_id WHERE (thread_id = 73 AND msg_box != 3 AND (msg_box != 3)) ORDER BY normalized_date ASC) ORDER BY normalized_date ASC
```

where 73 is the thread ID. In lollipop and kitkat , it works fine. But in marshmallow, it returns "0" new messages.

Please help me here.

Was there any changes in native SMS DB params in marshmallow???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue occurs because in marshmallow, there is a restricted access in viewing SMS. A SQL view is created named "sms_restricted" and it contains only MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX and MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT. That is alone exposed to other application developers.

The failed messages, draft messages, outbox messages, queued messages are not accessible unless our application is made as "Default Messaging application".

Answer (score 2):

in marshmallow,get permission should be runtime

```
   final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;       


   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
         //your code here
     }else {
        requestContactPermission();
    } 



    private void requestContactPermission() {

    int hasContactPermission =ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);

    if(hasContactPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }else {
        //Toast.makeText(AddContactsActivity.this, "Contact Permission is already granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    }


   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[]       permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            // Check if the only required permission has been granted
            if (grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Log.i("Permission", "Contact permission has now been granted. Showing result.");
                Toast.makeText(this,"Contact Permission is Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.i("Permission", "Contact permission was NOT granted.");
                } 

             break;

    }
}
```

Comment: see this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with this uri : content://sms/inbox

Comment: Can you please explain what issue yu foresee here? when it works in lollipop, why is it not working in marshmallow?

Comment: content://mms-sms/conversations content provider is not part of the Android sdk. It is part of the firmware. So is not accessible by Android application.

Comment: actually am able to fetch the messages in the "INBOX" . the problem happens when I try to fetch the messages that is sent to Invalid number... What I see is, it has errorCode: 29 when I see "Message details"...